# Providing params to manually loaded Xib files before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xib

Is there any possible way to provide a view that has been loaded manually from a Xib file with parameters **before** viewDidLoad get's called (because I'd need these parameters already inside viewDidLoad)?

I'm loading Xib files simply with:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(name, owner: owner, options: options)
```

And immediately after that, the viewDidLoad method gets called. There is obviously no way to override and call any initializer manually.

I'm not really sure what the options argument does. Could it be used to provide parameters to the loaded Xib's view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of method to pass options to a nib loaded manually.
The way I would go is one of the following:

- have few properties in your view controller that you will use to customize the initialization. You will have to set them up before you put the view controller in the hierarchy.
- have a configuration block in your view controller that you will invoke at the end of the viewDidLoad in order to fetch the configuration options you need

In both cases the entity instantiating the view controller will have to set either properties or block before pushing the view controller.
This will work because the viewDidLoad method [is called just the first time the view is accessed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:), so you still have time between loadNibName and when the view controller's view is actually loaded.

**UPDATE with code**

You would have to add an instance property to

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
   var setupOptions: [String: String]
   ...
}
```

and then, from the caller:

```
YourViewController *yourVC = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(name, owner: owner, options: nil)[0]
yourVC.setupOptions = ["key1" : "val1", "key2" : "val2"]
// Then push the controller to the hierarchy. Only after this the viewDidLoad is called.
// You will be then able to use the stored setupOptions for any custom initialization.
```

This is of course just an example. The nature of the *setupOptions* depends on your use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you mind giving an example? I guess by your first suggestion you don't mean static (class) properties? In any case, calling a custom method (e.g. setup()) in the Xib's view controller is always called after viewDidLoad, even if I call it right after the load call.

Comment: Thanks for the example Nicola. Tried it but it doesn't work. setupOptions is still nil in viewDidLoad. I would have been surprised if it had worked to set properties before viewDidLoad but method calls would at the same time not work.

Comment: have you tried to use [initWithNibName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:) on the view controller instead of loadNibNamed?

Comment: Actually initWithNibName by its nature can only be used in the VC class, not in the VC class that uses the Xib's VC class so that would require some bigger changes in architecture, such as not using the VC class as the base class in the Xib for instance. I'm not sure if it is worth it. I'd much rather prefer to load a Xib into a view controller where the Xib's VC is used.

Comment: I don't understand the point, but maybe because I didn't understand the bigger picture of your case. Where are you calling the loadNibWithName? What I meant is just to initialise the instance of the view controller that you want to push by means of initWithNibName instead of the other one. With the only purpose of having more control on when the VC lifecycle callbacks are invoked.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more advanced, elegant way to solve this but I managed to get it working with the somewhat inelegant method like this:

1. Make a static (class) var in the Xib's view controller that keeps a reference to the VC that needs to provide params to it.
2. Make an options VO class (or a dictionary) and create it/set the params in it before the Xib is loaded and store in a var in the class.
3. Access the VO in the loaded Xib's viewDidLoad from the var on the static class.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to keep your viewDidLoad method clear..
Then, after you've set your properties, call a custom method that will use these properties like so:

*MyCustomController.h*

```
- (void)setupView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *test;
```

*MyCustomController.m*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)setupView {
    // this will work perfectly because this method is being
    // called AFTER self.test is set
    NSLog(@"test: %@", self.test);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
- (void)goToNextController {

    MyCustomController *controller = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomController" owner:self options:nil];

    // viewDidLoad will be called at this point..
    // so setting properties here will be useless.

    controller.test = @"our custom message here";
    [controller setupView];

    // so after our property('s) are set.. we call the "setupView" method.
    // the output would be: "test: our custom message here".

}
```